# Checkout behavior is inconsistent when opening files from sharepoint

Tags: check-out

Can anyone tell me why it makes a difference, whether I open Office documents from the browser or through the office app, and why it does even depend on what files they are?

Specifically:

1 I open a Word Docx from IE11 
-> an info bar will appear in Word that indicates that I must first click on edit to check out the document and make it writable. Before, I cannot make any changes to the document, the input is blocked! This is the desired behavior!

2 I open the same document using the recent file list or jumplist within word -> it is not checked out, but the input is not blocked and I can also save! That is undesirable.

3 If I open an Excel sheet from within IE11, the same bar appears as in 1), but neither the input is blocked nor is the sheet checked out - just as undesirable because some users are too blind to see this bar.

We use Sharepoint 2016 and Office 2016 on Win10 v1803. Everything is patched and this "problem" is always reproducible.

In short: is this behavior adjustable in Office? I know that we could make checkout mandatory, but that is not what we want.